# Calling fragment from acivity when a button is clicked

Tags: android

I am creating an app with  fragment ,here i want to call fragment continuously when a button is clicked.eg when a button next is clicked i want to dispaly 5 fragment when the button clicked every time.

Here is my xm code

[the image shows my  xml design.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yjpz.png)

i want to display the fragment in the framelayout .

Answer (score 0):

try this may be it helps you

```
    FragmentManager manager;
    manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentOne fragment = new FragmentOne();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout,fragment).commit();
```

Comment: thank for your reply,but i want to call 5 fragments in same place,when single button is clicked it want to call fragment at same place.each time call diffrent  fragment when the same button  is clicked.

Comment: i am not understand what exactly you mean. 5 fragments in same place and at same time

Comment: eg Fragment A,B,C,D,E. fragments named from a - z when a button(next) is clicked means it want to call A fragment,then the same next is clicked means it want to call B fragments and  so on.. in the same framelayout. The button next is static and it is diplayed below the framelayout.

Comment: how is it if you put your fragments to ArrayList and then replace it one by one